# How can I set Google App Engine/Apps to allow non-admin users engine app use of sub domain

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps

So I have a domain, lets call it example.com and I'm already using Google Apps with this domain (email, sites, etc). The administrator for this account is admin@example.com. I have an App engine application called myapp and I want it to be accessed via myapp.example.com, but I DONT want to use the admin@ user to host/control the application, I want to use a less privileged account myapp@.

I've already tried giving this user privileges to "Domain Settings", but I still get access errors when I try to add example.com.

How can I allow the myapp@ users App Engine application to use myapp.example.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've found a slightly ugly means to make this work.

Step 1: Assign the role "Super Admin" to the myapp@ user via the admin@ account on Apps (this is temporary).

Step 2: Login to App Engine as myapp@ and run through the process of adding the domain to the application then assigning a sub domain. Once complete and working sign out.

Step 3: Sign in again to Apps as admin@ and remove "Super Admin" privileges for myapp@.

This still leaves the sub domain assigned to the application and you can control this from the dashboard of admin@. myapp@ is still in control of the application, but if you wanted to change the domain settings you'd probably need to repeat steps 1-3.